# White border around picture after saving in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, png, gif, borders

I'm making a logo in PS which is gonna go on a website. It is supposed to be just the logo and the main background of the webpage. But when I either save in `.png` or `.gif` format I get a small white border around the image.

[image]

This is the settings I used for PNG:

[image]

And this is the settings I used for `.gif` format:

[image]

When I saved as a `.png` file not only was the border there, but some of the logo was in a really bad quality. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you not using Save for web? Are the edges crisp and sharp before you try and save? Why not use PNG24?

Comment: None of the choices made will give you a border. Two questions: 1) is your example image a snapshot of the website (your image imposed in a rendered webpage)? 2) can you share a screenshot shot of the image before you save it; especially with layer info?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, it would be best to save for web, ensure that there are no extra layers turned on before you save it. As for your quality problem, are you sure of your image size and resolution? If so then your trouble is stemming from your save preferences.

Good luck!